# Returning std::string from one object's method

Tags: c++, stl

I need to return std::string:

```
IntegerValue::(std::string) toString() {
    std::string a = std::to_string(this -> value);
    return a;
}
```

But GCC compiler says "Syntax error". What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return type syntax is invalid. `IntegerValue::(std::string)` this is wrong.
Either use plain `std::string` or `typedef` it in your class and use this type.
You cannot use brackets in there.

Edit:

I noticed you just put the class scope identifier in wrong place. It should be before the method's name, not return type. Originally I thought you wanted to use some special string type from your class.

`std::string IntegerValue::toString()`

That is all to it.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is:

```
std::string IntegerValue::toString() {
    std::string a = std::to_string(this -> value);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax and semantic is

```
const std::string IntegerValue::toString() const
{
    const std::string s{std::to_string(this->value)};

    return s;
}
```